Microsoft Engage Embedded feed - Images won't enlarge
I am using the Engage Embedded feed feature. If you go to a engage community you can get a link using Embed community feed link. It gives something like the following code to put on your html site: (click the ellipsis button, then you have the option to get the community feed link)
<iframe name="embed-feed" title="Viva Engage" src="https://engage.cloud.microsoft/embed/groups/GroupID" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 400px;"></iframe>

This works fine, but when you hover over an image that has been posted the mouse changes like you can click to enlarge the image, but nothing happen when clicking it. Straight from the engage site this works as expected. Has anyone ran into this?
